# Storing time series data in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm thinking through a redshift schema to store time series data minute by minute. When thinking about the problem in other column oriented databases (like cassandra), I was going to store my record to track as the row and each column would be a period of time. This isn't possible in redshift because of the 1,600 maximum column limitation. What would be the proper way to store this?

Answer (score 1):

I would just store this as a single column:

```
CREATE TABLE time_series_data (
  data_timestamp timestamp sortkey distkey,
  data_measurement float
);
```